# How can I zoom into only a portion of a PNG for interpretation

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pdftex, zooming

Hello guys I have a PNG picture. and i would like to zoom into a portion of it for the reader to see the changes made by my algorithm. How can i do this. I have MWE below:

```
\documentclass[margin=0.1cm] {standalone}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[version=0.96]{pgf}
\begin{document}

\insertimage{example-image-a}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this is for trimming. but thanks for your input. the solution below is what i was looking for.

Comment: Once the image is trimmed you can zoom it by making the graphic larger (`scale=2` or `height=..,width=..`). This is more or less what the solution below also does, but then using an additional package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[margin=0.1cm] {standalone}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[version=0.96]{pgf}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\newsavebox\myzoom
\begin{document}
\sbox4{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\savebox\myzoom{\clipbox{.5\wd4{} .25\ht4{} .3\wd4{} .55\ht4}{\copy4}}
\scalebox{5}{\usebox\myzoom}
vs.
\copy4
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is perfect. Thanks alot