# Horizontal image with no indentation on left and right for journal publishing

Tags: indentation, journal-publishing

I am currently writing a research papers and the reviewers asked me to increase the image size. Currently, it is shown as:

[image]

The problem is that the IJSEKE journal template only allows images to be set in the same width as the text. Trying to increase the image with scaling only moves it to the right side but not the left. See the image example shown here:
[image]

I have tried making image vertical as well by putting `\begin{landscape}` next to image code and the output is as under:
[image]

But that still doesn't work well.

I have tried changing the orientation of the page to landscape but no success.

Is there a way I can remove the indentation on the left side of the image so that reviewers can see the image clearly? or any other solution wrt to journal's template

MWE is

```
\documentclass{ws-ijseke}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}
\markboth{Author}
{Paper title}
\title{Title}
\section{Adding Image}
\lipsum[1-3]
%\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure*}[htb]%
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/test.png}
\caption{The caption}\label{fig2}
\end{figure*}
%\end{landscape}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the actual png image contains empty space on its left margin, you may be able to apply a `\clipbox` to the image(`trimclip` package), in order to remove the dead-space.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Could you provide an example code?

Comment: For example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597741/how-can-i-zoom-into-only-a-portion-of-a-png-for-interpretation/597742#597742

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I have tried this but didn't work with the template...:(

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the issue.  Is something like the following what you seek? `\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth]{example-image}}`